# Aspect fit in cgsize programmatically in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uilabel, cgrect, cgsize

[Click here for image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leswD.png)

Need help fitting label so that the left and right side fills. 
Code is at the bottom.

```
  @IBOutlet weak var header: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    header.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

    let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
    rectShape.bounds = self.header.frame
    rectShape.position = self.header.center
    rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.header.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft , .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width:300, height: 200)).cgPath

    self.header.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    //Here I'm masking the textView's layer with rectShape layer
    self.header.layer.mask = rectShape


    super.viewDidLoad()
```

Comment: do you want to fill that blue header to left and and right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this issue by put the code block into the `viewDidAppear(_:)`. In this method, the size will be corrected.

```
@IBOutlet weak var header: UILabel!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    header.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

    let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
    rectShape.bounds = self.header.frame
    rectShape.position = self.header.center
    rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.header.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft , .bottomRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width:300, height: 200)).cgPath

    self.header.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    //Here I'm masking the textView's layer with rectShape layer
    self.header.layer.mask = rectShape
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! That helped!